# can use useRef hook to empty the input value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form

I used useRef at this component and it's work well when I need to refer to the input value, but when I finish and click the submit button, it's work well but the input field still have the work I wrote

simply, I need to empty the input field when click submit, **Without using useState and Onchange function because it causes too renders**

is there any method at useRef that helps me to empty the input field

here is the Code

```
const AddTodoForm = () => {
  const inputRef = useRef()

  const createTodo = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const todoRef = fire.database().ref("Todo");
    const todo = {
      title: inputRef.current.value,
      complete: false
    };
    todoRef.push(todo)

    // I Need To Empty input value here

  }

  return (
    <form>
      <input type="text" ref={inputRef} />
      <button onClick={createTodo}> Add Todo </button>
    </form>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clear the input after submit the to do is the way.

```
  const AddTodoForm = () => {
  const inputRef = useRef()

  const createTodo = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const todoRef = fire.database().ref("Todo");
    const todo = {
      title: inputRef.current.value,
      complete: false
    };
    todoRef.push(todo)
    inputRef.current.value = ""
  }

  return (
    <form>
      <input type="text" ref={inputRef} />
      <button onClick={createTodo}> Add Todo </button>
    </form>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks, man
I tried to do this solution before asking, but it didn't work for me because I was typed 
``` == ``` two equals :)
thanks  a lot

Answer (score 1):

Just get current DOM in rer and set value ""(`inputRef.current.value = "";`). Example:

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from "react";

export default function DisableElevation() {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);

  const addTodo = (todo) => {
    setTodos([...todos, todo]);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <AddTodoForm addTodo={(todo) => addTodo(todo)} />

      {todos.map((todo) => (
        <div> {todo.title} </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

const AddTodoForm = ({ addTodo }) => {
  const inputRef = useRef();

  const createTodo = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const todo = {
      title: inputRef.current.value,
      complete: false
    };

    inputRef.current.value = "";
    addTodo(todo);

    // I Need To Empty input value here
  };

  return (
    <form>
      <input type="text" ref={inputRef} />
      <button onClick={createTodo}> Add Todo </button>
    </form>
  );
};
```