# More than needed React components re-rendering when typing in input

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am taking input from a search input field using `searchInput` and `setSearchInput` useState hook and after I press submit button, I call `fetchSearchData` function providing it the input text and `setCompanies` hook, where `companies` are updated with the fetched list of companies from the API.

Then `companies` are passed to another component `CompanyList` where a map function is called there.

The problem is whenever I type in the search field, the `CompanyList` component is re-rendered although I did not press submit. I understand that `setSearchInput` will re-render `SearchBar` component whenever I type in it, but I don't get why `CompanyList` re-renders.

`Search` page source code:

```
const Search = () => {
    const [companies, setCompanies]=useState([]); //List of companies returned from searching
    const [searchInput, setSearchInput] = useState(""); //Search field input

    //Update search text whenever the user types in
    const onSearchChange = (e) => {
        setSearchInput(e.target.value)
    }

    //use the API providing it the search input, and 
    //setCompanies hook to update list of companies
    const onSearchSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        fetchSearchData(searchInput, setCompanies)
    }


    return (
        <div>
            <Container>
                <Row className={"searchFilterBar"}>
                    <Col sm={6} md={8} className={"searchBar"}>
                        <SearchBar onSubmit={onSearchSubmit} onChange={onSearchChange} value={searchInput} />
                    </Col>
                    <Col sm={6} md={4} className={"filterBar"}>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
                <CompanyList companies={companies} ></CompanyList>
                <Row>
                </Row>
            </Container>
        </div>
    )
}
export default Search;
```

`SearchBar` component source code:

```
const SearchBar = ({value,onSubmit, onChange}) => {
    return (
        <Form
            className="search-form"
            onSubmit={onSubmit}
            >
            <div className="input-group">
                <span className="input-group-text rubik-font">
                    <i className="icon ion-search"></i>
                </span>
                <input
                    className="form-control rubik-font"
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="Search for companies that start with..."
                    onChange={onChange}
                    value={value}
                />
                <Button className="btn btn-light rubik-font" type="submit">Search </Button>
            </div>
        </Form>
    )

}
```

`CompanyList` component source code:

```
function MapDataToCompanyList(response) {
    console.log(response); //Logging occurs here
    if(!response || response===undefined || response.length===0)
    {
        return (<ErrorBoundary message={noCompaniesError.message}></ErrorBoundary>)
    }
    return response.map((company) => {
        return (
            <Col key={company._id} xs={12} md={6} lg={4} className="mt-2">
                <CompanyCard
                    id={company._id}
                    logo={company.logo}
                    title={company.name}
                    logoBackground={company.logoBackground}
                    progLangs={company.progLangs}
                    backend={company.backend}
                    frontend={company.frontend}
                    url={company.url}
                >
                </CompanyCard>
            </Col>
        )
    })
}
const CompanyList = (props) => {
    const {companies} = props
    return (
        <div>
            <Container className="mt-3">
                <Row>
                    {
                    MapDataToCompanyList(companies)
                    }
                </Row>
            </Container>
        </div>
    )
}

export default CompanyList;
```

`FetchSearchData` function source code:

```
export const fetchSearchData = (query, cb)=>{
    const uri = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ?
    `http://localhost:3000/api/companies/name/${query}` :
    ``;
    axios.get(uri, {
        timeout: MAX_TIMEOUT
    })
    .then((response)=>{
        cb(response.data.data)
    })
    .catch((error)=>{
        console.log(error)
    })
}
```

[image: Screenshot for the re-rendering problem]

As seen above, empty list of companies is logged when the page first loads, then I typed three characters and the it logged three time which means the map function called three times.

[image]

Even then if I pressed submit and retrieved list of companies normally, whenever I type it will keep printing the array of companies that was fetched.

Sorry if I missed something, I am still new to React.

Comment: Try to add 'e.preventDefault()' in the onChange function

Comment: You understood why this happens by reading the below answers. Now, if you really want to see how many times `CompanyList` will be infact re-rendereder, you could use a `useEffect` with empty deps list like: `useEffect(() => {
    console.log("CompanyList rendering");
  });`

Comment: I'm sure you made a typo, but just pointing out that this is not "empty deps" (onMount) that is "undefined deps" (everyRender)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `setSearchInput(e.target.value)`, `Search` component will re-render cause its state has changed. `Search` component re-renders means every tag nested in it will re-render (except the ones passed via `children`). That is the normal behaviour of React. If you want to avoid that, you would wanna use `React.memo` for `CompanyList`. Or you could use `useRef` to bind the `input` like so:

```js
const Search = () => {
  const [companies, setCompanies] = useState([]); //List of companies returned from searching
  const inputRef = React.useRef(null);
  //use the API providing it the search input, and
  //setCompanies hook to update list of companies
  const onSearchSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    fetchSearchData(inputRef.current.value, setCompanies);
    inputRef.current.value = "";
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Container>
        <Row className={"searchFilterBar"}>
          <Col sm={6} md={8} className={"searchBar"}>
            <SearchBar inputRef={inputRef} onSubmit={onSearchSubmit} />
          </Col>
          <Col sm={6} md={4} className={"filterBar"}></Col>
        </Row>
        <CompanyList companies={companies}></CompanyList>
        <Row></Row>
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Search;
```

```js
const SearchBar = ({ onSubmit, inputRef }) => {
  return (
    <Form className="search-form" onSubmit={onSubmit}>
      <div className="input-group">
        <span className="input-group-text rubik-font">
          <i className="icon ion-search"></i>
        </span>
        <input
          ref={inputRef}
          className="form-control rubik-font"
          type="text"
          placeholder="Search for companies that start with..."
        />
        <Button className="btn btn-light rubik-font" type="submit">
          Search
        </Button>
      </div>
    </Form>
  );
};
```

Comment: The answer below has a link to another question regarding clearing the input after submit. Now If I used this approach, then I won't need to use `onChange` neither `setSearchInput` hook, right?

Comment: Yeah you don’t need them anymore.

Comment: I just tried it now and it works well I believe, alsoI will try to read more about `useRef`. Thank you so much!

Comment: And I saw that link and updated my answer.

Answer (score 4):

You do not need to maintain a state for input field. You can use `useRef` and pass it to input like below.

```
<input
  ref={inputRef}
  className="form-control rubik-font"
  type="text"
  placeholder="Search for companies that start with..."
/>
```

And you can get get value inside `onSearchSubmit` using `inputRef.current.value`

This will not re-render you component on input change.

Comment: Look at this answer for further help
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63884055/can-use-useref-hook-to-empty-the-input-value

Answer (score 2):

> I don't get why CompanyList re-renders.

Because it's nested in your Search component, and it's not `React.memo`'d (or a `PureComponent`).

Yes, the component is updated, but that doesn't mean it necessarily causes a DOM reconciliation.

In any case, React is completely at liberty of calling your component function as many times as it likes (and indeed, in Strict Mode it tends to call them twice per update to make sure you're not doing silly things), so you should look at side effects (such as console logging) in your component function (which you shouldn't have in the first place) as performance guidelines.

Comment: So it is completely normal, right? Also will `useRef` make it more efficient regarding the re-rendering issue as suggested by the comments below?  Thanks for your consideration

Comment: It's normal. If you use refs, you'll have an uncontrolled input, which may or may not be what you want.